# Add, remove subview and communicate between subview and main uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, addsubview

I have created two uiviewcontrollers in storyboard. I am adding second UIview as a subview to 1st view when a button is pressed.

Now, my subview has a done and cancel button, which upon been touched, the subview has to be removed from the main view and needs to send some data back to main view. Is using delegates the only way to solve this? Please explain if there is any other simpler or better option.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the question is just about subviews of the 1st view controller's view.  In that case, the 1st view controller can directly inspect all of them.  i.e.  Say the data that you'd like "passed" between views is the text of a UITextField contained on the subview.

You have an outlet to the subview, probably painted in IB?

```
// MyViewController.m
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subview;  // self.view is it's parent
```

Create an outlet that connects to whatever subviews you want data from:

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;   // probably, subview is it's parent
```

Hide and show the "dialog":

```
self.subview.alpha = 0.0;  // to hide (alpha is better than 'hidden' because it's animatable
self.subview.alpha = 1.0;  // to show
```

When the button is pressed:

```
- (IBAction)pressedDoneButton:(id)sender {

     self.subview.alpha = 0.0;

     // or, prettier:
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ self.subview.alpha = 0.0; }];

     // the text field still exists, it's just invisible because it's parent is invisible
    NSLog(@"user pressed done and the text that she entered is %@", self.textField.text);
}
```

The point is that data is not being passed between views.  The view controller has pointers to views.  Some, like buttons generate events for the view controller to react to.  Others carry data that the view controller can see.

Comment: awesome!! thanks!! but if i use alpha instead of hidden..wont the buttons of subview trigger action when touched(in addition to main view button actions)?? @danh

Comment: No. When their parent alpha is zero, any subview will ignore touches.

Comment: Also, if subview is the parent for all the objects inside it, does that mean to create a different .h and .m for subvieW? @danh

Comment: Nope. It's part of a view's job to enclose subviews.  You'd use a new file to subclass a view to give it special new behavior. But it sounds like the default behavior is what you need.

Comment: ok..so can I declare the text fields in the mainview .h? how can i say subview is their parent? @danh

Comment: is there a way to dim the main view when the subview is presented and disable the userinteraction of main view??

Comment: To make subview the parent of a text field, either paint it that way in IB, or say [self.subview addSubview:textField];  to dim the main view, you can say self.view.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: when i do that..even the subview is dimming :( but i found out a way to do it..i am setting the main view background color and it is working!! Now, I would like to disable the userinteracion for buttons on main view. when i set self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO, even the subview is becoming disabled. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this ?? Thanks @danh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34313/discussion-between-danh-and-kedari-theja)